# How to redirect to the newly created record in record triggered flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, flow-builder, lightning-flow-builder

I'm using record triggered flow to create record. After the creation, I want the user to be redirected to the newly created record. Is there any way to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: record-triggered flows execute at the database level so they can't do user navigation

Comment: Do I need to change my flow type to something else to achieve this? Actually, based on a checkbox value of RecordType A, I have to create a new RecordType B record. Is there any alternative way to redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record-triggered flows execute at the database level so they can't do user navigation. They are akin to triggers, which also execute at the database layer and can't do navigation.

If you want to do navigation, you have to to start with a component that is something other than the standard SFDC record page UI. There are many examples:

- Lightning Page LWC or Aura component
- Custom button associated to a Visualforce page
- Lightning page screen flow component
- Record page Screen Flow quick action (or custom button)
- ...

Using whatever technology you choose, the end result is some redirection to a new record page.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect using platform events when record is created?

Comment: nope - platform events are executed at the database layer too

Comment: Thanks for you clear explanation